# Explanation on Haarlets

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection, wavelet

Would someone be able to give me some info or a link etc ... regarding **haarlets** aka **Haar wavelet-like features**. I'm reading several papers for my master dissertation and several of these papers briefly mention haarlets. I can't seem to really get what they are and how they are used. I apologize if this is a basic question. But i would really appreciate some clear, structured info on the subject.

Comment: i always thought they were sorta *"street women"*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you seen [Robust Real-time Object Detection](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/viola/Pubs/Detect/violaJones_IJCV.pdf) by Viola and Jones?  This is probably the most widely used face detection algorithm, and also the most famous example of the use of the Haar wavelet-like features.

Answer (score 2):

The Haar wavelet is used for edge detection and edge detection is a common problem in image processing, specially for pattern recognition. Haarlets are recommended for that purpose. As an example, this project uses haarlets to achieve that:

Bergh, M, Koller-Meier, E, & Gool, L 2009, 'Real-Time Body Pose Recognition Using 2D or 3D Haarlets', International Journal Of Computer Vision, 83, 1, pp. 72-84, Computers & Applied Sciences Complete, EBSCOhost.